# Number of subset-permutations for a set

Tags: permutations

Suppose you have a set `{a, b, c}`.

There are `3! = 6` permutations.

Subsets `{a, b}`, `{a, c}`, and `{b, c}` will account for `3 * 2! = 6` permutations.

Subsets `{a}`, `{b}` and `{c}` accounts for `3 * 1! = 3` permutations.

Subset `{}` accounts for `0! = 1` permutation.

So `{1, 2, 3}` has `6 + 6 + 3 + 1 = 16` subset-permutations.

---

How do I generalize this to a formula for a set of length `n`? I figure we need to sum with `i` from `1` up to `n`, and include `i!` in the sum body. But I can't figure out how to write it down!

Comment: So are you purposely missing out empty set?

Comment: Oh! Forgot about that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm such a math dope!

Comment: It should be $\sum \limits_{i=0}^n i!{n\choose i}$. I don't know whether you can simplify the formula.

Comment: Ah yes that is correct and I understand! Thank you so much. Why don't you promote this comment to an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i!{n\choose i}$.

Comment: And note that $\binom{n}{i}=\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

One useful (and lazy) way to find out more about about a series is to use OEIS to look it up from the first couple terms. In this case, our series is "number of permutations of subsets of $n$ elements". You could calculate the first couple terms by hand. Another option is to write a program, like this Haskell I cribbed from OIES:

```
import Data.List
subsetPerms setSize = length $ concatMap permutations $ subsequences [0 .. setSize]
map subsetPerms [0 .. 5]
```

This shows that the first terms are $2,5,16,65,326,1957$. (Note that in Haskell, the range `[0 .. n]` is inclusive, so the first term it prints is finding subset-permutations of the set $\{ 0 \}$ instead of subset-permutations of the empty set.) Then, [paste it into OEIS's search box](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C16%2C65%2C326%2C1957&sort=&language=english&go=Search) and we find it's A000522 "Total number of arrangements of a set with n elements: a(n) = Sum_{k=0..n} n!/k!."

There are a couple formulas listed.

One is the simple formula [Jack Yoon's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/813629/12609): $a(n) = Sum_{k=0..n} binomial(n,k) * k!$ (which is described as "interpretation: for all k-subsets (sum), choose a subset (binomial(n,k)), and permutation of subset (k!). - Joerg Arndt, Dec 09 2012")

Another is the expanded version $a(n) = Sum_{k=0..n} n!/k!$ in the sequence's title.

A third is a recurrence relation: $a(n) = n*a(n-1) + 1, a(0) = 1$

Finally, a particularly neat closed form: $a(0) = 1$; for $n > 0$, $a(n) = floor(e*n!)$

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I was asking the same question, so when I found this thread, I put the formula in Wolframalpha. It gave $$e\Gamma(n+1,1)$$ where $\Gamma$ is the incomplete Gamma function.